# Automatically document @PathVariable annotated parameters within @ModelAttribute annotated methods

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

In our REST-API we need to be multi-tenant capable. For achiving this all rest controllers subclass a common REST controller which defines a request mapping prefix and exposes a model attribute as follows

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{tenantKey}/api")
public class ApiController {

   @ModelAttribute
   public Tenant getTenant(@PathVariable("tenantKey") String tenantKey) {
     return repository.findByTenantKey(tenantKey);
   }

}
```

Derived controllers make use of the model attributes in their request mapping methods:

```
@RestController
public class FooController extends ApiController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = GET)
  public List<Foo> getFoo(@ApiIgnore @ModelAttribute Tenant tenant) {
    return service.getFoos(tenant);
  }

}
```

This endpoint gets well documented in the swagger-ui. I get an endpoint documented with a GET mapping for path `/{tenantKey}/api/foo`.

My issue is, that the {tenantKey}  path variable is not documented in swagger-ui as parameter. The parameters section in swagger is not rendered at all. If I add a String parameter to controller method, annotating it with `@PathVariable("tenantKey)` everything is fine, but I don't want a `tenantKey` parameter in my controller method, since the resolved tenant is already available as model attribute.

So my question is: Is there a way do get the `@PathVariable` from the `@ModelAttriute` annotated method in `ApiController` documented within swagger-ui in this setup?

Project-Setup is

- Spring-Boot (1.4.2)
- springfox-swagger2 (2.6.1)
- springfox-swagger-ui (2.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible. Model attributes on methods are not supported currently. Instead, you could take the following approach.

1. Mark the `getTenant` method with an `@ApiIgnore` (not sure if it gets treated as a request mapping.)
2. In your docket you can add `tenantKey` global path variable (to all end points). Since this is a multi-tenant app it's assuming this applies to all endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I configured a global path variable and this perfectly solves my problem. Btw: The `getTenant` method isn't treated as request mapping. It don't get documented in any way, but this is the behavior I'd expect, since it only works internally and don't have any influences to the REST API.